# How to correct error in swap image jQuery code?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create code to swap images in a table based on values from a database. After some research on this site, I have this code, amended for my needs. Not dynamic at this point as the input data at this point is hard coded. The jQuery is not working because I have missed the point on something. Very new to jQuery so would appreciate any help to point me in the right direction.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td id="td1">
      <img />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
      $('#td1 img').attr('src' function(){
          
return parseInt($(this).parent().prev().html()) > 5 ? 'src1','/images/clubsTiny.png' : 'src2','/images/blkCross.png';
});
  </script>
```

Comment: Two issues in your syntax. Firstly you need to put a `,` between the arguments in `attr()`. Secondly you need to remove `'src1',` and `'src2',` from the ternary in the function. Then your code will work. Voting to close as the issues are due to typos. For future reference, when JS code doesn't work as expected open devtools and check the console for errors. They will tell you the issue and what line it's on.

Comment: Some basic debugging would've solved your own issue

Comment: Thanks Rory for the solution and the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First separate  `$('#td1 img').attr('src', function ()` by `,`. Note that
`attr` needs two parameter and each parameter seprates with `,`.

And then changed condition with:

```
return parseInt($(this).parent().prev().html()) > 5 ? 'images/clubsTiny.png' : 'images/blkCross.png';
```

Note that ternary conditions is `expression ? 'do true one' : 'do false one'`

```js
 $('#td1 img').attr('src', function () {
            return parseInt($(this).parent().prev().html()) > 5 ? 'src1/images/clubsTiny.png' : 'src2/images/blkCross.png';
        });
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td id="td1">
      <img />
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Update**

For replace content by `img` you can use `$('#td1').html(img)`

```js
function replace() {
    let td = $('#td1');

    let img = $("<img />");

    img.attr("src", ()=> +td.html() > 5 ? 'images/clubsTiny.png' : 'images/blkCross.png')

    $('#td1').html(img)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="td1">
            6
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="replace()">click to replace</button>
```

Comment: Well almost, the correction from Rory helped greatly but I was trying to replace the number with the image rather than place it next to it.

Comment: @codestruggler number is in another `td` and image is in  another one. what do you mean? what is your expected result?

Comment: thanks, looks like I need to study this some more. I am looking to replace a number in a td with an image instead, not have both. I have data coming from a database into a table and if the value is more than 6 show one image and less that 6 show another.

Comment: Ok I'm going to update my answer with simple value. and replace it with some image

Comment: Thanks!  Alireza, that helps me very much and I appreciate your help. I need to study this to see how it works and adapt it.  I never need to see the number and do not need a button to change it. I just want the image to appear in the table based on the value coming from the database. The number in the td will change coming from the database. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Just to help any other newcomers possibly looking at this code, and could be confused, src1 and src2 should be removed as they are not part of the image file path nor pay any function in the code. As originally pointed out by Rory McCrossan who explained the errors in the original code.